# How to enforce Camel not to interpret or change data coming from a queue?

Tags: queue, apache-camel, ibm-mq

The goal of my Camel route is to read messages from a queue and to write the content of each message body as a file to a directory. It's not much more than the following:

```
from("wmq:..")
    .to("/some/path");
```

The message body is always text. *However*, I don't want Camel to interpret it as text - instead, each message body should be seen as binary data that is written to the file system without applying any changes to it.

The background of my problem is that there are a lot of producers writing to the queue. The messages in the queue are always textual, but with different encodings, and different message headers (or the lack thereof). The problem is that some (non-unicode) messages that end up as a file in `/some/path` suddenly got a UTF BOM prepended by Camel while others are totally fine. My assumption is that this has something to do with the heterogenous message headers of the incoming messages which I can't control.

How can I enforce Camel to just write the content bytes of a message to a file without applying any changes to it?

---

**edit:**
I asked the wrong question, or at least I asked it in a wrong way. I'll give it another try with a slightly different wording:

In Camel, is it possible to create a route that takes the bodies of queue messages and writes them to the file system, ...

- with the guarantee that the content is not altered (on byte level)
- regardless of the message headers that might or might not be present, or even indicate a wrong content type

The route should be robust in the sense that no matter what kind of queue message you throw at it, it just writes the content to the file system.

And if this is possible, is the simple route I posted above already doing that, or is it necessary to implement additional measures?

Comment: charset property of the file producer. However you would need to know it before hand. See this documentation: http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/file2.html

Comment: I highly doubt Camel would add BOM character. I would suspect this is added by the system generating the messages. You can verify this but stopping the Camel route. Save the message to disk and view it in nodepad++ or some other editor that shows the hex value of the BOM character.

Comment: Yeah especially if you use IBM WebSphere MQ where it may be more common to use different encodings coming from IBM systems or other legacy hosts.

Comment: I made the question too complicated. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I am a MQ admin and know little about Apache Camel. In reviewing the Apache Camel docs I think you need to do something like this `from("wmq:queue:MY_QUEUE?mapJmsMessage=false").to("/some/pat‌​h");`. If this works I'll write it up as a answer with links and quotes from the docs I found. Let me know if it works.

Comment: did my suggestion work?